# JButton does not go to next card

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I need to switch between multiple panels using a JButton, the fist panel works properly however the button doesn't switch to the other panels.This is the main class with the Cardlayout and the button to switch panels using cardLayout.next();.   I'm not to sure what to do next.

```
public class MainPanel{
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static JFrame  frame;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JPanel cards;
    private static int panelChanger = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]){

        frame = new JFrame ("Draw");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        LinearPanel panel = new LinearPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        CirclePanel panel2 = new CirclePanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);

        AbsPanel panel3 = new AbsPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel3);

        JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(panel, "LinearPanel");
        cards.add(panel2, "CirclePanel");
        cards.add(panel3, "AbsPanel");

        button = new JButton("Next");
        button.setForeground(Color.white);
        button.setBounds(250,10,100,60);

        button.addActionListener( new ButtonListener());
        frame.add(button);

        frame.getContentPane().add(cards);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        int a = 0;

        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
       
    }
    static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
       
        
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource() == button){
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
                cardLayout.next(cards);
             
               
                frame.revalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to set your `cards` field, but `JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());` declares a *brand new variable* with the same name, so your `cards` field is still null.

Comment: Why are you adding the panels to both the content pane `frame.getContentPane().add(panel);` and the cards JPanel `cards.add(panel, "LinearPanel");`? Either use one or the other. I don't recommend using the contentpane directly, but if you do, then make sure you set the layout to card layout. Possibly helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: Forgot to add but it switches panels in the main method but it started having issues when we put into an actionlistener.

Comment: @VGR I found in the console there was a java.lang.NullPointerException. I'm not too sure what a cards field is can you explain in further detail.

Comment: Thank you all for the help I fixed the code. There was an issue with  Cardlayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();, it needed to be declared in the constructor and have it be cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();.